# How to get the absolute path of the contact URI?

Tags: android

I am getting uri as content://com.android.contacts/data/592 . I need to convert this in to absolute path . How to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What means "absolute path" for this type of content?

Comment: Full path name.. I need to know where it is stored in sd card For eg

Comment: c:/mydocuments/xxx  like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contacts are not stored in files , they are stored in a database , you can use the content resolver to get that contact information.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html